# Why does Math.min work with a one element array

Tags: javascript, math

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) Math.min accepts only numbers, and if one of the arguments is not a number, it'll return `NaN`. It's true that if we pass an array with multiple numbers we get `NaN`, like this: `Math.min([1,2])`, but if we use an array with just one number, `Math.min` will return the the number in the array, like in this example: `Math.min([5])`. Does anyone have an idea why we see this undocumented behavior?

Comment: It's JavaScript.  This is [far from the weirdest type conversion/coercion issues you'll find](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqhZZNUyVFM) in the language...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) `Math.min` accepts only numbers, and if one of the arguments is not a number, it'll return `NaN`.

That's not what it says (**bold** emphasis mine):

> If at least one of arguments **cannot be converted** to a number, the result is [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

Type Conversion:

- [`Math.min`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.min) uses `ToNumber` to convert its arguments.
- [`ToNumber`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber) uses `ToPrimitive` to convert `Object`s (and `Array`s are `Object`s).
- [`ToPrimitive`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive) uses `toString`
- [`[5].toString()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.tostring) is `'5'`, which gets returned to `ToPrimitive`, which returns it to `ToNumber`, which parses it to `5` and returns it to `Math.min`, for which it is a valid argument, because it is not `NaN`.
- `[1, 2].toString()`, OTOH, is `'1, 2'`, which gets returned to `ToPrimitive`, which returns it to `ToNumber`, which parses it to `NaN`, because it is not a valid number representation. `ToNumber` then passes `NaN` to `Math.min`, which will then return `NaN`, because (as MDN states it) "one of its arguments cannot be converted to a number" or (as the spec states it) "If any value is NaN, the result is NaN.".

Comment: The ECMAScript spec is actually surprisingly readable, I just found out.

Comment: Yes. The `Number([1,2]);` results NaN but `Number([1])` results 1.